# "Closed" form for $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} i^{[(i,n)=1]}$?

Tags: number-theory

> How could we derive a closed form for $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}
>  i^{[(i,n)=1]}$?

Here "$[s]$" is the [Iverson bracket](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IversonBracket.html) and "$(a,b)$" is the [greatest common divisor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestCommonDivisor.html).

Comment: I don't think it is derivable but I would call it an Eulerial. :)  I guess some bounds can be derived from those that are known for the totient function itself.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65390/effective-bounds-on-eulers-totient

Comment: More a restatement than a closed form, but: $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{[\gcd(k,n)=1]}$ would be a compact way of putting it. Here $[p]$ is the Iversonian bracket.

Comment: BTW: there doesn't seem to be a closed form, but the product of all [totatives](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Totative.html) of a number is [listed in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001783).

Comment: @J.M:Wow,thanks for updating me with those names (totatives/iverson),Btw is it iversonian or [iverson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) bracket ...

Comment: "Iversonian bracket" and "Iverson bracket" are the same thing. :)

Comment: @J. M:I thought so,one more thing I guess $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{[\gcd(k,n)=1]} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{[\gcd(k,n)=1]}$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a Gauss Factorial, and is used frequently in Modular arithmetic.  It satisfies a theorem analogous to [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), and can be also be thought of the $p$-adic gamma function.

Define $$N_n !:=\prod_{{1\leq j\leq N}\atop{\gcd(j,n)=1}} j.$$

We have the following congruence: $$(n-1)_n!\equiv \begin{cases}
-1\pmod n & \text{for }n=2,4,p^{\alpha},p^{2\alpha}\\
1\pmod n & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Lastly,  $$\Gamma_p(z)=\lim_{N\to z} (-1)^N (N-1)_p !$$ where $N$ runs through any sequence of positive integers $p$-adically approaching $z$.

**Remark:** If you want some other form, inclusion exclusion implies that for squarefree $n$, $$n_n! =n!\prod_{d|n}\left(d^{\frac{n}{d}}\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)!\right)^{\mu(d)}, $$  where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: If there's no closed form, and it shows up a lot anyway, then make it your own closed form...